# How to do facets with date (Datehistogram) on Symfony2 : Fos ElasticaBundle

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, twig

how to do a facet and aggreagtion query with date in elasticsearch on symfony2 ?

thanks for your help!

Hugo.

I need to have this result : total of server by year.

Here is my code but, I have not of result or in my Twig I don't know how I can view a result.

Thanks.

Hugo

```
    $search = $this->get('fos_elastica.index.serveurs.serveur');

    $queryServeurs = new \Elastica\Query\MatchAll();

    $elasticaQueryServeurs = new \Elastica\Query();
    $elasticaQueryServeurs->setQuery($queryServeurs);
    $elasticaQueryServeurs->setSize(0);

    $elasticaAggregDateServeur = new \Elastica\Aggregation\DateHistogram('dateHistogram','dateGarantie','year');
    $elasticaAggregDateServeur->setFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");

    $typesServeursaggregation = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Terms('types');
    $typesServeursaggregation->setField("type");
    $elasticaAggregDateServeur->addAggregation($typesServeursaggregation);

    $elasticaQueryServeurs->addAggregation($elasticaAggregDateServeur);

    $resultsServeursDate[] =$elasticaQueryServeurs;
```

`return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('VefsiffReferentielsBundle:stats:stats.html.twig', array(
                                            'serveursdates' => $resultsServeursDate ));`

Comment: Please show us the query DSL you have so far and which needs to be translated to FosElasticaBundle.

Comment: Hello, I added my code thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a new code for aggregation with a date of serveur.
One condition for use DateHistogram : the field "dateGarantie" must be of type Date in your file config.yml.

Extract to the file config.yml :

```
dateGarantie: {type: date}
```

here extract to the file controller :

```
$search = $this->get('fos_elastica.index.serveurs.serveur');

    $queryServeurs = new \Elastica\Query\MatchAll();

    $elasticaQueryServeurs = new \Elastica\Query();
    $elasticaQueryServeurs->setQuery($queryServeurs);
    $elasticaQueryServeurs->setSize(0);

    $elasticaAggregDateServeur = new \Elastica\Aggregation\DateHistogram('dateHistogram','dateGarantie','year');
    $elasticaAggregDateServeur->setFormat("YYYY");

    $elasticaQueryServeurs->addAggregation($elasticaAggregDateServeur);
    $resultsDateServeurs = $search->search($elasticaQueryServeurs);

return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('refBundle:stats:stats.html.twig', array(
                                        'serveursdates' => $resultsDateServeurs->getAggregations()));
```

finally this is a code for twig. I use the code of Morris for have  beautiful graphs :

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
                         <h3>Serveurs à changer</h3>
                          <style>
                          #serveur2 {
                          width: 800px;
                          height: 300px;
                          margin: auto 0 auto;
                          </style>
                         <div id="serveur2"></div>

                         <script>
                         // Use Morris.Bar
                            Morris.Bar({
                              element: 'serveur2',
                              data: [ {% for serveursdate in serveursdates.dateHistogram.buckets %}
                                {x: '{{serveursdate.key_as_string}}' ,Total: {{ serveursdate.doc_count }} },

                              {% endfor %} ],
                              xkey: 'x',
                              ykeys: [ 'Total'],
                              labels: ['Total Serveur'],
                              barColors: function (row, series, type)
                                            {
                                                      if (type === 'bar')
                                                      {
                                                        var red = Math.ceil(255 * row.y /this.ymax);
                                                        return 'rgb(' + red + ',0,0)';
                                                      }
                                                      else {
                                                        return '#000';
                                                      }
                                            }

                            });
                         </script>


                         <hr>
            </div
```